# Renamed my heroku app stopped update my app from git

Tags: heroku

I renamed my heroku app from the site
then I applied these lines in my terminal

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a newname
```

But everytime I do some changes and push it to git I don't see these changes.
This happend only after I renamed my app, before that it works great.
any reason for that?

edit:

My app is getting deployed but nothing is getting change.
[image]

"Compare Diffs" :

```
<Link className='link' to='/shop'>
        Shop
        Shopp
      </Link>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "push it to git"? Are you pushing to GitHub / GitLab / Bitbucket / etc.? Or pushing to Heroku's Git repository?

Comment: Hi, pushing to GitHub and I am using heroku option that  automaticlly deploys

Comment: Then you'll probably have to reconfigure your automatic deployment.

Comment: I tried everything. The only thing which works is to delete public folder and run npm run build again after every change but there is must be a better solution

Comment: What does that have to do with configuring deployment? Where do you delete the folder and run `npm build`? I don't see how that's relevant at all.

Comment: The problem is my app is not getting updated.
I am following Heroku guide on pushing changes to the app and I see on activity log that my app is getting re deployed but nothing has change.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the log in question. You can paste it as a code block, like you have done already for the commands above.

Comment: What do you mean by log in question? Sorry I don't think I understand it :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed a word. I was just asking to see your log, where it shows that your app was redeployed. Is `d84effc1` the commit you expect to see there? What kind of application is this? Based on your `npm build` comment, I guess it's a Node.js project? Please also show us your `package.json`.